# Spring Boot 2 is ignoring HikariCP properties set in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, hikaricp

I have a spring boot 2 app which connects to Mariadb database. This app runs in cloud foundry. It takes database connection properties from VCAP_* env variable.

App works fine and can connect to database. But, I have found out that app is not using hikari configuration specified in application.yml.

Can you please suggest what is wrong here?

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'

    compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.6.2'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
}
```

application.yml

```
   datasource:
    hikari:
      pool-name: mypool
      auto-commit: true
      connection-timeout: 5000
      minimum-idle: 8
      maximum-pool-size: 8
      idle-timeout: 600000
      max-lifetime: 3600000
```

CloudConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {

  @Bean
  public CloudFactory cloudFactory() {
    return new CloudFactory();
  }

  private DataSource createDataSource(CloudFactory cloudFactory, String serviceId) {
    return cloudFactory.getCloud().getServiceConnector(serviceId, DataSource.class, null);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "myDataSource")
  public DataSource becscmDataSource(CloudFactory cloudFactory) {
    return createDataSource(cloudFactory, "my-maria-rds");
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what `cloudFactory` does, so guessing the usage of `DataSource.class` doesn't recognize the hikari properties - try `HikariDataSource.class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Spring Cloud Connectors library to create the database connection.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector', version: '2.0.7.RELEASE'
```

This library is in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors#spring-cloud-connectors-), and its use is discouraged. One of the reasons for discouraging its use is that it does not work well with Spring Boot configuration. When Connectors APIs like `cloudFactory.getCloud().getServiceConnector()` are used to create the service connection bean, Spring Boot auto-configuration backs off and properties like `spring.datasource.*` are ignored. If there is a reason why you must continue to use Connectors, then you will need to use the Connectors API to configuring pooling options as [shown in the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server).

The better option is to remove the dependency on Connectors and use [Java CFEnv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv) instead.

Answer (score 1):

After following Scott's suggestion. I was able to make it work as follows.

`build.yml`

```
implementation 'io.pivotal.cfenv:java-cfenv-boot:2.3.0'
```

`application.yml` stays same

`CloudConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "myDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari") // added this
  public DataSource becscmDataSource() {
    CfJdbcEnv cfJdbcEnv = new CfJdbcEnv();
    CfJdbcService myJdbc = cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcServiceByName("my-maria-rds");

    DataSourceBuilder builder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    builder.url(myJdbc.getJdbcUrl());
    builder.username(myJdbc.getUsername());
    builder.password(myJdbc.getPassword());
    builder.driverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```